# Change generated code for 'Check if parameter is null'

Tags: templates, resharper

Is there any way to change the code generated by resharper for the context action 'check if parameter is null'.
I want to change it from

```
if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
```

to

```
Contract.Requires(item != null)
```

Comment: look at these two blog post directly from jetbrains blog 1) http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/ 2) http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/11/resharper-nullreferenceexception-analysis-and-its-contracts/ Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks punker, I have looked at those articles, the first one deals with the annotations and the warnings that pop-up, as of my version of resharper this seems to be built in (6.1).
The other article deals with custom patterns, but not specificially about changing the code created by 'check if parameter is null'. I need to change the code that is generated when that context option (alt-enter) is selected.

Comment: I found this: (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Add_Edit_Highlighting_Pattern.html) It seems to be the only way it can be done. You generate the default code, and then add a new pattern rule to change that code into an assert. You cannot actually change the original generated code - or so it seems.

Comment: Have you considered implementing this yourself (i.e., writing a R# plugin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [the Reference "Add_Edit_Highlighting_Pattern"](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Add_Edit_Highlighting_Pattern.html). It seems to be the only way it can be done. You generate the default code, and then add a new pattern rule to change that code into an assert. You cannot actually change the original generated code - or so it seems.

The  procedure described in another article "[From ArgumentException to CodeContracts using Resharper](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2010/12/13/From-ArgumentException-to-CodeContracts-using-Resharper.aspx)"